# Can I use one connection to postgresql and use it to make concurrent queries?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, multithreading, knex.js

I write in nodejs with knex, and I want to update multiple rows in the db, and I wondered if I can execute multiple update queries in parallel,

like this:

```
const updatesPromises = books.map((book) =>
    transaction('books')
      .where({ id: book.id })
      .update({ title: book.name }, ['id', 'title'])    

await Promise.all(updatesPromises)
```

instead execute each update query synchronously, like this:

```
books.forEach(async (book) =>
    await transaction('books')
      .where({ id: 42 })
      .update({ title: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" }, ['id', 'title'])
```

- `transaction` is a connection I created before, and commit after all the updates

Is this best practice?

Can it cause problems in large scale?

Comment: Nodejs doesn't use multiple threads here.

Comment: The I/O is occurred parallely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wondered if I can execute multiple update queries in parallel

No. A single connection only supports sequential execution of queries. `node-postgres` doesn't stop you from issuing multiple calls at once, but it does queue them internally, so you won't get any benefit from creating all promises at once and calling `Promise.all` on them.

<sub>(That said, I don't know how Knex `transaction` works, if it uses a [connection pool](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling) it might not actually limit you to a single connection. However, that is not a best practice if you serve multiple HTTP clients, you should use only connection per HTTP request.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using transaction, the best practice is to do them sequentially one after another.

Also error handling is pretty nasty in your case, if one of the queries fail, but `Promise.all()` may keep on sending queries to the transacation which is already rolled back.